# MongoDB query performance over shard key

Tags: mongodb

My collection stores emails and has a ShardKey on N (known) digits, dash and another digit, aka `1234-9`... the first for digits are calculated based on the users Email and the last digit is the last digit second the email was sent. So, all the emails to/from `youremail@domain.com` are stored in the shards 1234-0 up to 1234-9.

Now, I don't have a database big enough to test this in a meaningful way, so I decided to ask here: which query would be more efficient?:

- `find({"ShardKey":{$regex:/^1234-/}})`
- `find({$or:[{"ShardKey":"1234-0"},{"ShardKey":"1234-1"},{"ShardKey":"1234-2"},... and so on]})`

Details:

- Each shard is expected to have around 20k documents when the system is "matured"

Comment: Why do you not simply use the mail as shard key?

Comment: because then I would have A LOT of shard keys, each with very few documents ( possibly 1 document only) and that is not recommended...

Comment: What/where is that not recommended at?

Comment: You can use `explain()` to get a query plans and execution statistics on the queries.

Comment: Where did you read that? You can use even the primary kay as shard key - provided it is not a sequence number because then all new documents would be inserted into a single shard. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/

Comment: How big are your documents? The default Chunk size is 128 MiB. When the average document size is less than 6k then 20k documents would be still in a single shard.

Comment: What about `{ ShardKey: {$in: ["1234-0", "1234-1", "1234-2"]} }`? But as I already mentioned, you better choose a different shard key.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you for pointing out the default chunk size. My document avg size is about 200 bytes! Would you happen to know how Atlas handles this?

Comment: I didn't read it explicitly about "don't have a shard key for each document" but I inferred from my general understanding of mongo... like The primary purpose of sharding in MongoDB is to distribute data across multiple servers (shards) efficiently. A good shard key leads to an even distribution of data and workload. If each shard key corresponds to only a single document, this could lead to a massive number of shards with very little data on each, which is inefficient...

Comment: No, of course  not. Every shard holds a RANGE of values. And you don't need to take care about it, MongoDB takes care and defines the ranges for even distribution.